# Python, I want to loop back to the main menu after a ynbox but it loops back immediately without it

Tags: python

I am working on a conference room reservation program for school and I am trying to loop back to the main menu. After you select the time a ynbox should open with yes and no and when you click yes it should loop back but now it does loop back but without a ynbox.

Can someone look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am a beginner.

```
from easygui import *

text = "Reserveer uw vergaderruimte. Maak een keuze:"
title = "Vergaderruimtes reserveren"

menu1 = ["Reservering maken",
         "Reservering verwijderen"]

rooms1 = ["Vergaderruimte 1",
          "Vergaderruimte 2", 
          "Vergaderruimte 3"]

days1 = ["Maandag",
         "Dinsdag", 
         "Woensdag",
         "Donderdag",
         "Vrijdag"]

times1 = ["09:00 - 10:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00",
          "11:00 - 12:00",
          "12:00 - 13:00",
          "13:00 - 14:00",
          "14:00 - 15:00",
          "15:00 - 16:00",
          "16:00 - 17:00"]

times2 = ["09:00 - 10:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00",
          "11:00 - 12:00",
          "12:00 - 13:00",
          "13:00 - 14:00",
          "14:00 - 15:00",
          "15:00 - 16:00",
          "16:00 - 17:00"]

times3 = ["09:00 - 10:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00",
          "11:00 - 12:00",
          "12:00 - 13:00",
          "13:00 - 14:00",
          "14:00 - 15:00",
          "15:00 - 16:00",
          "16:00 - 17:00"]

message1 = "Uw keuze:"
message2 = "Uw keuze is opgeslagen"

finished = False

while not finished:
    
    output = choicebox(text, title, menu1)
    
    if output == menu1[0]:
        
        message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
        
        output = choicebox(message, title, rooms1)
        
        if output == rooms1[0]:
            
            message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
            
            output = choicebox(message, title, days1)
            
            if output == days1[0]:
                
                message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
                
                output = choicebox(message, title, times1)
                
                if output == days1[1]:
                    
                    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
                    
                    output = choicebox(message, title, times1)
                    
                    if output == days1[2]:
                        
                        message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
                        
                        output = choicebox(message, title, times1)
                        
                        if output == days1[3]:
                            
                            message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
                            
                            output = choicebox(message, title, times1)
                            
                            if output == days1[4]:
                                
                                message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)
                                
                                output = choicebox(message, title, times1)

                                output = ynbox("Are you finished?")

                                finished = True

# Vergaderruimte 2

if output == menu1[0]:

    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, rooms1)

if output == rooms1[1]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, days1)
    
if output == days1[0]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times2)

if output == days1[1]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times2)

if output == days1[2]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times2)

if output == days1[3]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times2)

if output == days1[4]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times2)

# Vergaderruimte 3

if output == menu1[0]:

    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, rooms1)

if output == rooms1[2]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, days1)
    
if output == days1[0]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times3)

if output == days1[1]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times3)

if output == days1[2]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times3)

if output == days1[3]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times3)

if output == days1[4]:
    
    message = "Geselecteerd: " + str(output)

    output = choicebox(message, title, times3)
```

Comment: Did you seriously write a `if` statement for every single choice?

Comment: I'd recommend you look at how loops work (some of your code can be done by iterating the elements of a list) and how functions work. You can also read about dictionaries. Read a bit about the language before making a big program with lots of checkings. You will see that your code can be restructured and hugely simplified. As a rule of thumb, every time you are typing some code that is almost identical to some previous code is a sign that this could probably can be done as a function or in a loop